# Not supported exception with TruncateTime entity framework function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm getting an exception when trying to use TruncateTime() in my linq expresion
and I'm not sure why?

Here is my statement

```
var yogaProfile = dbContext.YogaProfiles.Where(i => i.ApplicationUserId == userId).First();

var yogaEvents = yogaProfile.RegisteredEvents.Where(j => 
       (j.EventStatus == YogaSpaceEventStatus.Active || j.EventStatus == YogaSpaceEventStatus.Completed)
       && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(j.UTCEventDateTime) > DbFunctions.TruncateTime(yesterday)
       && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(j.UTCEventDateTime) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(todayPlus30)
       ).ToList();
```

and here is the exception

> System.NotSupportedException: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.
>
> at System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(Nullable`1
>   dateValue)
>
> at
>   YogaBandy2017.Services.Services.YogaSpaceService.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.b__1(YogaSpaceEvent
>   j) in
>   C:\Users\chuckdawit\Source\Workspaces\YogaBandy2017\YogaBandy2017\Yogabandy2017.Services\Services\YogaSpaceService.cs:line
>   256
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.List'1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> at
>   YogaBandy2017.Services.Services.YogaSpaceService.GetUpcomingAttendEventCounts(String
>   userId) in
>   C:\Users\chuckdawit\Source\Workspaces\YogaBandy2017\YogaBandy2017\Yogabandy2017.Services\Services\YogaSpaceService.cs:line
>   255
>
> at
>   YogaBandy2017.Controllers.ScheduleController.GetEventCountsForAttendCalendar()
>   in
>   C:\Users\chuckdawit\Source\Workspaces\YogaBandy2017\YogaBandy2017\YogaBandy2017\Controllers\ScheduleController.cs:line
>   309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.NotSupportedException: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.

You have this exception because the result of `yogaProfile` variable is not an `IQueryable` which is used by Linq To Entities to perform query on server side. To make your variable to be an `IQueryable` you need to remove the extension method `First()` you use on the query at the end and replace it with `Take(1)`.

So instead of

```
var yogaProfile = dbContext.YogaProfiles.Where(i => i.ApplicationUserId == userId).First();
```

You should have this:

```
var yogaProfile = dbContext.YogaProfiles.Where(i => i.ApplicationUserId == userId).Take(1);
```

Note that with the first statement you are dealing with Linq To Objects when you perform Linq on the variable. By removing `First()` extension method and replace it with `Take()` extension method you'll perform Linq To Entites.